# Exchange Hybrid Mailbox Creation / Sync error

Tags: powershell, email, migration, exchange-server, hybrid

I have a hybrid environment with on-prem exchange (almost done migrating) and O365 Email.

I create a new user in our on-prem AD via powershell. It syncs properly via AADConnect to our Azure environment and creates the O365 user and Exchange online (O365) email account. Using powershell I can correct proxy addresses and the msExchRecipient/Remote attributes.

The expected result is that I have an email account on both sides for the hybrid environment, with the on-prem Exchange srerver showing the Mailbox Type as "Office 365".

For one particular user, I ended up with email accounts in both on-prem and online exchange as expected. The user receives messages in their O365 account. However, messages that are trapped by our Mimecast server are not getting through. The Mailbox Type listed in on-prem is "User". This is messing up the mail routing for incoming messages from outside the domain.

Is there a way I can powershell my way out of this mess and somehow convert the mailbox type from "User" to "Office 365"? I can't migrate the user because the account already exists in O365. If I delete the O365 I would lose the email.

Should I have my powershell user creation script create the ad user, create the on-prem mailbox and also perform the migration? At least until we are fully migrated and out of our hybrid environment?

For this user, would it work to delete the AD and on-prem Exchange, and re-create both manually? How would I connect the on-prem to online exchange without losing the mail?

Any insight into this can of worms would be greatly appreciated.

One of the documents I referenced is this one about Recipient Type Values:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/recipient-type-values/7c2620e5-9870-48ba-b5c2...

: Keith

Comment: This is probably better suited for server fault or another forum.

Comment: Basically skip the on-prem mailbox. Our procedure is to create the user in on-prem AD, it get's synced to Azure Active Directory. Then when we assign the O365 E3 license, they automatically get their Exchange Online mailbox set up (i.e. no manual scripting setup). No migration required.